# Bluedio T5s headphones with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I have had decent behaviour with Bluedio T4s headphones with Ubuntu via bluetooth, but am now using Bluedio T5s headphones and they are not working well via bluetooth.

After making the bluetooth connection, sound continues to come out of the headphone jack. In fact the T5S does not even show up as an output option under Sound Settings

When, occasionally, it does work, my music on rhythmbox pauses itself every few minutes. I just have to unpause it for the music to continue. This does not happen through other sound output channels than the new bluetooth device.

I am looking for how to fix these problems.